# Synchronize angular execution with for loop

Tags: angular, reactive, filechooser

I am working with Angular 9 project with backend as Spring Boot. The project is basically in CMS type.
In this user can generate form using reactive form. A form may contains more than one file chooser. I have implemented the code to choose file and uploading file at local path.

This code working fine, but I am having the issue to synchronize the saving of instances in the database.

My flow should be :

1. Upload File(s) in loop
2. Get objectform updated with uploaded data.
3. Then objectform with remaining options and updated uploaded data should be saved to database.

But my flow is not going in correct way, it going in upload and without waiting to return result it go for saving database, so the updated details are not getting saved.

Below is the code flow :

**Click event from button Save to save the form data :**

```
saveClick() {
    for (const element of this.objMetaData) {
      if (element.fieldType === 'file-upload') {
        this.uploadAttachment(element.fieldName);
      }
    }
    this.saveToDatabase();
  }
```

**This should be saved last with updated details :**

```
saveToDatabase() {
    let relations = [];
    const instanceBody = {
      objectTypeId: this.objectTypeId,
      objectInstance: {...this.objectFormGroup.value, relations: relations}
    }
    this.saveInstance(instanceBody);
  }
```

**Uploading of the file and upating the object to save the data :**

```
uploadAttachment(fieldName: string) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let fileObj: any = this.fileMap.get(fieldName);
    let fileName = fileObj.name;
    if (fileObj !== undefined) {
      formData.append('file', fileObj);
      this.attachmentService.uploadAttachment(formData).subscribe((result) => {
        if (result != null) {
          let attachmentDir = result;
          let attachmentFileName = fileName;
          let attachment = attachmentDir + '**' + attachmentFileName;
          this.objectFormGroup.value[fieldName] = attachment;             
        } else {              
          console.log("File not uploaded.")
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

The code flow not going as the flow.

> this.saveToDatabase();

This is get called before upload happen in for loop. I have tried many thing like updated forEach to for loop, async, await etc, but not working fine.

How to resolve the issue to make execution synchronize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, the way to go here would be using [Rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/). Get all Observables from the *uploadAttachment* function and combine them with [combinelatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest). Then subscribe to this combined hook to run *saveToDatabase* only once all calls have returned.

In code it would render something like

```
saveClick() {
    let observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
    for (const element of this.objMetaData) {
          if (element.fieldType === 'file-upload') {
            let uploadObservable = this.uploadAttachment(element.fieldName);
            if(uploadObservable) observables.push(uploadObservable);
          }
    }
    combineLatest(observables)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .toPromise()
    .then(()=>{ 
        this.saveToDatabase();
    });
}
```

Also for this to work, we need the *uploadAttachment* function to return the upload observable.

```
uploadAttachment(fieldName: string): Observable<any> {
    // ... 
    return this.attachmentService.uploadAttachment(formData)
    .pipe(tap(result=>{ 
        // ... Callback code goes here 
    }));
}
```

Notice i'm using the [Rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) operators pipe, take and tap.

If you don't know yet i believe you should really take a look at over [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators). There's also an [article](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) about rxjs on angular's website.

Edit: Added [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-evgwta)